# Subdomain routes dont seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

Wondering why my routes don't work with what was described in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html). `http://admin.foo.dev:3000/` takes me to the `root_path`, and not `admin::pages#home`.

The first approach works though. Which was taken from [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised).

```
# WORKS!

match '', to: 'pages#home', constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && r.subdomain != 'www' }

# does NOT work!

namespace :admin do
  constraints :subdomain => "admin" do
    root :to => 'pages#home'
  end
end
```

I have everything setup in `/etc/hosts`. It looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 api.foo.dev admin.foo.dev foo.dev www.foo.dev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your route is inside a namespace, the correct page that would take you to `admin::pages#home` would be `http://admin.foo.dev:3000/admin/`. Remove the namespace to connect correctly.

In general, if you're ever confused what routes are being generated and how to get to them, use `rake routes`. And for more on namespacing routes (and why you might not want to use namespaces in situations like this), check out [the Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).